# Cannot find module '@angular-persian/material-date-picker' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker, angular-material, jalali-calendar

I'm trying to use [Persian Jalali DatePicker for Angular Material](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-persian/material-date-picker) in my project.
So far, I have installed the package:

```
npm i --save @angular-persian/material-date-picker
```

But when I try to import it in my Angular project like so,

```
import {MatDatepickerModulePersian} from '@angular-persian/material-date-picker';
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot find module '@angular-persian/material-date-picker' or its
> corresponding type declarations.

Comment: The pre-requisites are all installed,right? Have you ng served the app after installing it?

Comment: @WahabShah yes, I just ng served it but I'm still getting the `cannot find module '@angular-persian/material-date-picker'.` error.

Comment: The compiler can't resolve the module. Look at *node_modules* folder in order to check the module structure then employ adoptive strategy to help typescript find it based on your environment configuration.

Comment: @NewshaNik Please explain how it solved.

Comment: Actually @KhalilLaleh I was mistaken. It is not fixed.

Comment: @AmirhosseinMehrvarzi unfortunately it didn't help. I looked at the node_modules folder and saw that I was actually giving the correct path. So... I don't really know what else  I need to do.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I have never used that dependency. Sometimes you have to do some handy tricks in *node_modules*. So don't rely on package managers (e.g `npm`) to do the best. Sometimes, prior versions may work better. So be innovative in such this time consuming cases.

Comment: @AmirhosseinMehrvarzi no I didn't. I decided to use the ng-persian-datepicker instead and that worked fine for me. So I stuck with that.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to add "/src" to end of import

`import {MatDatepickerModulePersian} from '@angular-persian/material-date-picker/src';`

Comment: Thanks. it was the answer

Comment: Somebody should fix the GitHub page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-persian/material-date-picker